# Temp was not declared in this scope when getting values from bool

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

Hello I wanted to change some voids to bools and I am a little lost. I understand if you write a void or a bool and want to add the values to the next void you just insert the code to add the previous function

I don't know how to explain it I am just gonna tell you what I want to do:

created a new bool getValues and added all the value getting code from the sensors  then I wanted to send the data to void loop that will send the data through mqqt to raspberry.

I understand that bool is for true and false. but I don't really understand the etiquette of using it

so the problem I am getting `'temp' was not declared in this scope` at the void loop function

I highlighted the function with // where I get the error it's almost at the bottom

```cpp
#include "DHT.h"
#include <WiFi.h>

#define DHTPIN 25  // Digital pin connected to the DHT sensor
#define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11

//MQTT Setup Start
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#define mqtt_server "192.168.1.210"
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
#define mqttlightReadingpercent "greenHouse/light"
#define mqttsoilmoisturepercent "greenHouse/soil"
#define mqtttemp "greenHouse/temp"
#define mqtthum "greenHouse/hum"
//MQTT Setup End

const char* ssid = "Cgates_E031F1"; // ESP32 and ESP8266 uses 2.4GHZ wifi only
const char* password = "60E541C32F";

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
const byte lightPin = 33;
int lightReading;
int lightReadingpercent=0;
//const int RELAY_PIN = 15;  // the Arduino pin, which connects to the IN pin of relay

// soil moisture
const int AirValue = 4095;   //you need to replace this value with Value_1
const int WaterValue = 2200;  //you need to replace this value with Value_2
const int SensorPin = 32;
int soilMoistureValue = 0;
int soilmoisturepercent=0;

const int Lightvalue = 0;
const int Darkvalue = 4095;

unsigned long millisNow = 0; //for delay purposes
unsigned int sendDelay = 20000; //delay before sending sensor info via MQTT
 

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println();

  // begin Wifi connect
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.disconnect();
  delay(2000);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
 
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  //end Wifi connect

  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
 
  //  pinMode(RELAY_PIN, OUTPUT);//relay

  pinMode(lightPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(SensorPin, INPUT);
  
  Serial.println(F("DHTxx test!")); //dht
  ; 

  dht.begin();
}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  int counter = 0;
  while (!client.connected()) {
    if (counter == 5) {
      ESP.restart();
    }
    counter+=1;
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Attempt to connect
   
    if (client.connect("greenHouseController")) {
      Serial.println("connected");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

bool getValues() {
  lightReading = analogRead(lightPin); //0-4095 12bit -- esp8266 10bit 0-1023 -- arduino 8bit 0-254
 
  Serial.print("Light reading = ");
  
  lightReadingpercent = map(lightReading, Darkvalue, Lightvalue,  0, 100 );
  Serial.print(lightReadingpercent);
  Serial.println(" %");
  Serial.println();

  soilMoistureValue = analogRead(SensorPin);  //put Sensor insert into soil
  soilmoisturepercent = map(soilMoistureValue, AirValue, WaterValue, 0, 100);

  if (soilmoisturepercent > 100) {
    Serial.println("Soil moisture ");
    Serial.println("100 %");
    delay(500);
  }
  else if(soilmoisturepercent <0) {
    Serial.println("Soil moisture ");
    Serial.println("0 %");
    delay(500);
  }
  else if (soilmoisturepercent >=0 && soilmoisturepercent <= 100) {
    Serial.println("Soil moisture "); //go to next line
    Serial.print(soilmoisturepercent);
    Serial.println("%");
    delay(500); // soil end
  }

  delay(500);

  // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
  // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (its a very slow sensor)
  float hum = dht.readHumidity();
  // Read temperature as Celsius (the default)
  float temp = dht.readTemperature();
  // Read temperature as Fahrenheit (isFahrenheit = true)
  float f = dht.readTemperature(true);

  // Check if any reads failed and exit early (to try again).
  if (isnan(hum) || isnan(temp) || isnan(f)) {
    Serial.println(F("Failed to read from DHT sensor!"));
    return 1;
  }

  // Compute heat index in Fahrenheit (the default)
  float hif = dht.computeHeatIndex(f, hum);
  // Compute heat index in Celsius (isFahreheit = false)
  float hic = dht.computeHeatIndex(temp, hum, false);

  Serial.print(F(" Humidity: "));
  Serial.print(hum);
  Serial.print(F("%  Temperature: "));
  Serial.print(temp);
  Serial.print(F("C "));
  Serial.print(f);
  Serial.print(F("F  Heat index: "));
  Serial.print(hic);
  Serial.print(F("C "));
  Serial.print(hif);
  Serial.println(F("F"));

  delay(500); //wait 0.5seconds
}


void loop() {
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }

  if (millis() > millisNow + sendDelay) {
    if (getValues()) {
      client.publish(mqttlightReadingpercent, String(lightReadingpercent).c_str(),true);
      client.publish(mqttsoilmoisturepercent, String(soilmoisturepercent).c_str(),true);
      client.publish(mqtttemp, String(temp).c_str(),true); // the problem is here
      client.publish(mqtthum, String(hum).c_str(),true);
      millisNow = millis();
    } 
  }

  client.loop();
 
  /*if (moisture_level < 10) {
    digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, HIGH); // turn on pump 5 seconds
    delay(5000);
  } 
  else {
    digitalWrite(RELAY_PIN, LOW);  // turn off pump 5 seconds
    delay(5000);
  }*/
}
```

Comment: You’re missing a bunch of closing braces after all those nested if/else clauses. Formatting your code properly would make this error more apparent,

Comment: The way you wrote your code it seems `float temp` exists inside `bool getValues() { }`. So no wonder you can't reach it inside `void loop() { }`

Comment: Yea the code is messy cause its made of examples for the sensors trying to clean it up and put all the code in the right places :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By moving your code to `getValues`, you also changed the scope in which your `temp` variable exists in. Variables are not automatically globally available. If you declare a variable inside a function (which `getValues` is), it's only available in this function.

When you try to access the `temp` variable in your `loop` function, the compiler rightly tells you, that there is no such variable available.

You could solve the problem by declaring `temp` as a global variable, which you would do by adding `float temp = 0` up on top where you also declare variables like `soilMoistureValue`. Make sure not to redeclare the variable in `getValues` then, so instead of declaring like so `float temp = dht.readTemperature();` you just assign a new value like so `temp = dht.readTemperature();`

A quick note on your first paragraph: The voids and bools how you call it, define the return type of a function. If your function does not return anything, you define it as void. If it returns a boolean value (so true or false), you define so bool. In the case of your `getValues` function, since it does not return anything, it should be `void getValues`.